# Reusable component to wait for data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

in many of my components I am fetching API data and therefor I need to wait until that data was loaded. Otherwise I am getting errors because some methods are, of course, not available.

My api query looks like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    prismicApi(prismicEndpoint).then((api) =>
      api.form('everything')
      .ref(api.master())
      .query(Prismic.Predicates.at("my.page.uid", this.props.params.uid))
      .submit((err, res) => {
        if (res.results.length > 0) {
          this.setState({doc: res.results[0]});
        } else {
          this.setState({notFound: true});
        }
    }))
}
```

For that I've created this structure that I have been using in all of these documents:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.notFound) {
      return (<Error404 />);
    } else if (this.state.doc == null || !this.state.doc) {
      return (<Loading />);
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="page">
                {this.state.doc.getSliceZone('page.body').slices.map(function(slice, i){
                    return (<SliceZone slice={slice} key={i} />)
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I wanted to move this into a component called Document that looks like this here:

```
export default class Document extends React.Component {
static defaultProps = {
    doc: null,
    notFound: false
}
static propTypes = {
    doc: React.PropTypes.oneOfType([
          React.PropTypes.object,
          React.PropTypes.array
    ]),
    notFound: React.PropTypes.bool.isRequired
}
render() {
    if (this.props.notFound) {
      return (<Error404 />);
    } else if (this.props.doc == null || !this.props.doc) {
      return (<Loading />);
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="page">
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
}
```

and then I tried to use it like this here:

```
<Document doc={this.state.doc} notFound={this.state.notFound}>           
{this.state.doc.getSliceZone('page.body').slices.map(function(slice, i){
    return (<SliceZone slice={slice} key={i} />)
})}
</Document>
```

Though on the second example the error messages are showing up quickly (until the data is loaded) and then disappear. What am I doing wrong? Why is the first example working and the second doesnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<Document doc={this.state.doc} notFound={this.state.notFound}>           
{ this.state.doc && this.state.doc.getSliceZone('page.body').slices.map(function(slice, i){
    return (<SliceZone slice={slice} key={i} />)
})}
</Document>
```

in your variant, you see an error becuase this.state.doc is null, untill data is loaded, and you see null reference exception, looks like.

In 1st case, it does not calculate, in 2nd case it calculates first and then sent as a parameter "children" to your Document control